# Dialog botton kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I take example from site https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/bottom-sheet-android/

repo this project -> https://github.com/probelalkhan/BottomSheet-Tutorial

And now i have problem[image] (see problem)
[image: expand and scroll dialog]
As you can see, the modal dialog does not open completely (it can scroll and expand to full screen), but I need the dialog to open completely.
You can tell me how to implement it.

I will be glad to hear your answers.

**Update**

I noticed this problem occurs on tablets.
Are there ways to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Material Design guideline says that the bottom sheet should peek at the height with which the area above the bottom sheet is 19:6. Since your landscape screen is shorter than 16:9, it peeks at the minimum height in the spec.

You can customize the peek height like this:

```
<style name="Theme.YourApp" parent="Theme.Design">
    <!-- other style configs -->
    <item name="bottomSheetDialogTheme">@style/GiveItSomeName</item>
</style>

<style name="GiveItSomeName" parent="Theme.Design.BottomSheetDialog">
    <item name="bottomSheetStyle">@style/BottomSheetStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="BottomSheetStyle" parent="Widget.Design.BottomSheet.Modal">
    <item name="app:peekHeight">256dp</item><!-- ***** The initial height you want ***** -->
</style>
```

Add this above layout in styles.xml which is present in res -> values -> styles

Make another change in bottom_sheet_modal.xml (Add background)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listViewOptions"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Add the white color in colors.xml